# How can I do Multiple Queries (build out a DB) in Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Really new to node.js and relatively new to PostgreSQL. For some reason this only creates the first table, not the second. I am probably totally doing this wrong. I can't seem to find any code examples that are similar enough to extrapolate an answer from.  I want to create two tables. It seems I can only run one query and that's it. No more. It's suggested that my connection ends before the second can be executed. I don't know why. I can't find a single example of doing this in a dozen different Google searches.

```
var client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
client.connect();
var query = client.query('CREATE TABLE preferences(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, food VARCHAR(40) not null, preferred BOOLEAN)');
client.query('CREATE TABLE foods(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, food VARCHAR(40) not null, type VARCHAR(40) not null, spicy BOOLEAN, spiciness VARCHAR(10)');
query.on('end', function() { client.end(); });
```

I had doubts that I could just do another client.query and have it all execute at the end. I took this example out of a tutorial but the second table I added. So I'm just playing with it and trying to learn here with this test.

Just to state my ultimate end goal: I wanna ultimately create a whole script for building out the database completely full of all the necessary tables and data.

Error I get no matter what I try:

$ node models/database.js
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
error: syntax error at end of input
    at Connection.parseE (~/Documents/test01/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:534:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (~/Documents/test01/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:361:17)
    at Socket. (~/Documents/test01/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:105:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:538:20)

Comment: You only waited for one of them to end, not the other, so you likely ended the connection prematurely.

Comment: From what I gathered (tutorials out there are awful) the query.on('end'... part ends the connection to the db. It gets throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event in the response. I'm still really confused at the moment.

Comment: `query.on(type, handler)` adds an event handler for the passed in type, "end" in this case. When that event occurs for the query you attached it to, the handler fires. Therefore, the handler fires when the first query is complete, which is likely before the second is complete.

Comment: Yeah no I'm still stumped.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle you never accepted any answer?

Comment: I don't know what happened with this, it was two years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to place all your requests into a transaction and execute it within the same connection.

Here's how you can do this with the help of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise):

```
var pgp = require('pg-promise')(/*options*/);
var db = pgp(connection);

db.tx(t => {
        return t.batch([
            t.none('CREATE TABLE preferences(id SERIAL, etc...'),
            t.none('CREATE TABLE foods(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, etc...')
        ]);
    })
    .then(data => {
        // success;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error); // print error;
    });
```

Better yet, is to place all SQL into external [SQL files](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#query-files), for which the library provides automatic support.

Comment: Yes, your library is awesome ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to perform two asynchronous actions, so you'll need to wait until both actions are complete before you continue. One way of doing this is with a count variable.

```
var client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
client.connect();
var query1 = client.query('CREATE TABLE preferences(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, food VARCHAR(40) not null, preferred BOOLEAN)');
var query2 = client.query('CREATE TABLE foods(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, food VARCHAR(40) not null, type VARCHAR(40) not null, spicy BOOLEAN, spiciness VARCHAR(10))');
var count = 2;

function endHandler () {
   count--; // decrement count by 1
   if (count === 0) {
       // two queries have ended, lets close the connection.
       client.end();
   }
}

query1.on('end', endHandler);
query2.on('end', endHandler);
```

Note that in this case you could likely just combine the two statements into one, assuming postgres supports that and that functionality is enabled in your system.

```
client.query('CREATE TABLE preferences(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, food VARCHAR(40) not null, preferred BOOLEAN);CREATE TABLE foods(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, food VARCHAR(40) not null, type VARCHAR(40) not null, spicy BOOLEAN, spiciness VARCHAR(10));')
```

Comment: (count === 0) Doesn't three equals signs refer to an equivalence in type?

Comment: Yeah this one doesn't seem to work, same error: events.js:85 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Comment: three `=` is type and value. i generally always use 3.

Comment: can you give the complete stack trace?

Comment: $ node models/database.js
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
error: syntax error at end of input
    at Connection.parseE (~/Documents/test01/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:534:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (~/Documents/test01/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:361:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (~/Documents/test01/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:105:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:538:20)

Comment: Gotcha. Add an error handler to your postgres connector. might simply be a sql syntax error.

Comment: as a matter of fact, that's exactly what it is. look at the end of your 2nd query. :)

Comment: Adding an error handler to the query will likely produce a more useful error.

Comment: I added this: var client = new pg.Client(connectionString, function(err) {
 if (err) {
  return.console.error(err);
 }
}); with no solid results of any kind. With your script, the preferences table still gets created, the latter table does not.

Comment: This time the error is:
  return.console.error(err);
        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3

Comment: You're missing a `)` in your second query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manage multiple 'query' variables. In your case the code could look like this:

```
    var client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
        client.connect();
    var queryPreferences = client.query('CREATE TABLE preferences(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, food VARCHAR(40) not null, preferred BOOLEAN)');

    var foods = function() { 
        var queryFoods = client.query('CREATE TABLE foods(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, food VARCHAR(40) not null, type VARCHAR(40) not null, spicy BOOLEAN, spiciness VARCHAR(10)');
        queryFoods.on('end', function() { client.end(); });
    }

    queryPreferences.on('end', foods);
```

In this way you are running the second query until you finish the first one and then you are closing the connection.

Comment: One thing i'm unsure of with your answer is whether or not the 'end' event works similar to a promise, in that if the end event has already occurred, will it immediately trigger any new events, or will it just do nothing because no event has happened since the handler was defined. however, in this case, i don't think it will matter because `client` is likely sending the requests in series rather than parallel, or the db will respond in series rather than parallel.

Comment: Thanks @KevinB and yeah, that was the point. Sending requests in parallel so all you have to worry about is closing the connection at the end of the last request. Note that the second event **end** it's subscribed to the **queryFoods** emitter.

Comment: Right, my concern was, what if `queryFoods` finishes first? but like i said, likely a non-issue due to this being a db connection, which generally are first in first out unless using separate connections.

Comment: Oh, now I understand and I'm with you. Probably is not an issue but to be sure I edited my answer. I think that could give me some peace about the order of the requests.

Comment: Same with this one: events.js:85 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event –  Apparently I'm doing something pretty new here. Not sure if anybody's created a JS to create a bunch of tables. I wanna ultimately create a whole script for building out the database completely full of all the necessary tables and data.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is unrelated to sending two queries, if neither of our solutions work.